# RouterLink on a button doesn't work but on <a> does

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my app.module, i am lazy loading modules.

```
  {
    path: 'user-dashboard',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/user-dashboard/user-dashboard.module').then(
        (m) => m.UserDashboardModule
      ),
  }, {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/register/register.module').then(
        (m) => m.RegisterModule
      ),
  },
```

So my project application is divided into multiple modules like in the picture shown. [Click to see the module structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNphx.png)

This below code is inside checkout.html which is a page inside register module. I wish to go to user-dashboard route

```
<button class="btn btn-primary form-btn payment-btn" [routerLink]="['/user-dashboard']">
     Confirm &amp; Pay
 </button>
```

In my user-dashboard-routing.module.ts, this is the route described

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserDashboardComponent,
  },
];
```

Now when i click this button, it goes to the desired route but returns to the same checkout page. It doesnot stay at user-dashboard. Also if i replace button with `<a>`, it will work.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description

Comment: @MikeS. If you can answer my question, please do.

Comment: can you try `(click)="javascript:void(0)"` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

For button you can use `(click)="someMethod()"`

```
someMethod()
{
    this.router.navigate([yourUrl])
}
```